# Get the current handled events with jQuery

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery

Is there a way to get all events that are currently handled? That means not the events that are bound to an element. I mean a way to get all events that are currently fired.

So for better interpretation, something like this (but without declaring each event):

```
var Records = {};
(function loop() {
  $(document).bind('click mousemove change', function(e) {
    Records[+new Date()] = {type: e.type};
  });
  setTimeout(loop, 10);
})();
```

I know about this: `$._data($('*').andSelf().get(0), 'events');` but that gives me only the currently handled/attached events.

Comment: Events can be stopped to bubble up to the `document` object that's the reason why this is complicated to achieve. (And, by the way, you don't need the `setTimeout`)

Comment: @Alexander yeah, you're right `setTimeout` is not needed here, but for my current project it is (to add the current event to my objects timestamp, even if no event is fired) ;)